# accessing user's email with a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I created a discord bot that needs to retrieve the user's email to perform some task. However, after I have changed the OAuth scope to email, my returned user property still doesn't have a email property.

this is my sample authorization URL:
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123456789&scope=email%20bot&permissions=268435506

and this is my test function:

```
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
console.log(msg.member.user);});
```

My returned user does not even have a email property.

```
user {
  id: '652349438404198401',
  system: null,
  locale: null,
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  username: 'Geek_.0',
  bot: false,
  discriminator: '8104',
  avatar: 'acba52ce51c54dacbcb2cba257c724af',
  lastMessageID: '812447507249889300',
  lastMessageChannelID: '809526161964531766'
}
```

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2