# access a user email address when he joins a discord channel and map the user with our own organization users

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, discord.net

Basically, I am trying to create a bot to access a user's email address and check its domain if it is our company user then map its Id to our own User entity in our database.

Simply, using a token and requesting `users/{user.id}` endpoint only has limited properties that does not include the email. There is also a similar thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286412/accessing-users-email-with-a-discord-bot) but in the comments section it says to use OAuth2.

Does that mean that each member has to give our bot the scope to use email separately. Can't we have a bot to automatically get a user email on GUILD_MEMBER_ADD event? Any tip is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Discord doesn't expose user's email nor ip to bots

Comment: @Paul-Marie what do you suggest as a workaround?

Comment: @ElhamKohestani You don't really have workaround, for privacy issues Discord won't provide these sensible data, so your only way is to ask yourself for these data, like having a landing channel where the bot will ask their email, if users send valid email then they are promoted with a Role allowing them to access to your servers channels / members.
Be aware of non Discord friendly users who won't quite understand it's basis, so make sure to send them a private message 1min after they join to ask their data (because newcommer easily don't read message with mention when they join a guild)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible through discord's API as Discord doesn't reveal personal user data such as emails to anyone who asks, to get a discord user's email you would have to get him to authorize your OAuth2 application which would require an http server.

You can read more about OAuth2 here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2